# <input type='file'> Browse button issue. Is there any alternate plugin to achieve the same?

Tags: plugins, button, css

I have written

```
<input type="file">
```

which results in one small text box along with browse button if i want to apply my custom CSS for this button then how do i do that?

Is there any plug-in to upload file from client to server where for button i can apply my own CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most browsers don't give you very much control over the styling of inputs of `type="file"`, and even if they did, you wouldn't get a very consistent appearance as the control is rendered differently by different browsers: in Chrome, for instance, there's no input field.

If you want to control appearances, consider a tool such as [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)

Comment: how do i use this plug in there is no demo or no where documented how should i start up with this

Comment: demo: http://www.uploadify.com/demos/
documentation: http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/

Answer (score 2):

You could definitely apply styles to the upload button. Here's a link which details achieve this. http://www.burhankhan.com/css_tricks/styling-file-upload-input-box-in-css/

Answer (score 1):

The options to style this element directly through CSS are very limited. One of the best know approaches to get around these limitations is this [one by Shaun Inman](http://www.shauninman.com/archive/2007/09/10/styling_file_inputs_with_css_and_the_dom).

Another option is an asynchronous upload using Flash, often done using [swfupload](http://www.swfupload.org/).